# create multiple records from comma separated email list in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, input

I am fairly new to rails and am trying to create multiple records from an array of comma-separated emails.

I am building simple event app where the user can send 1 invitation to many emails using a single form. When the user creates an invitation a Participant record is created and , if that record is saved, an invite email is sent.  I am creating the Participant record instead of using a token system so that RSVPs will be clearer.

I am having trouble getting the controller to read and separate the emails from the form.

I keep getting this:

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

Here is my code:

I tried two separate Controller Methods

Try 1

```
class ParticipantsController < ApplicationController
    def participant_invite
           @event = Event.find(params[:e])
           @email = params[:participant_invite][:email].split(/,\s*/)
           @participant = Participant.create!(event_id: @event.id, email: email_list,  level: 4, participant_cat_id: 3, added_by: current_user.id, status: 'unseen')
           respond_to do |format|
            if @participant.save
              format.html { redirect_to @participant, notice: 'Participant was successfully created.' }
              format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @participant }
            else
              format.html { render :new }
              format.json { render json: @participant.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
            end
          end
        end
```

Try 2:

```
def participant_invite
    @participant = params[:participant_invite][:email].split(/,\s*/)
    @participant.each do |p|
      newparticipant = Participant.new(:email => p)
      newparticipant.save
    end
    redirect_to tags_path
  end
```

The form:

```
<%= form_for :participant_invite, url: add_participant_path( :e => @event.id) do |f| %> 

<%=    f.email_field :email, :autofocus => true, :required => true, :maxlength => 55, :placeholder => 'Email(s)', :class => 'form-control'  %>

<%= f.submit 'Invite' %>
```

Models

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :participants

end

class Participant < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :event

end
```

trace with puts params.inspect

```
Started GET "/participants/participant_invite/276/1/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-01-04 19:52:24 -0800
Processing by ParticipantsController#participant_invite as HTML
  Parameters: {"e"=>"276"}
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.7ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 2  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1[0m

Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 57ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass):
  app/controllers/participants_controller.rb:91:in `participant_invite'


  Rendered /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (0.5ms)
  Rendered /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (0.9ms)
  Rendered /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (0.8ms)
  Rendered /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (12.1ms)
source=rack-timeout id=f896977ded104ababd4b01919c155066 timeout=10000ms service=461ms state=completed
```

Comment: Most likely you are not getting a value for `params[:participant_invite]`... it is nil... and then explodes when you try to call `[:email]` on it.

Comment: what version of Rails are you using? do you have require/permit in your controller?

Comment: Rails 4, I'm using     params.require(:participant).permit!

Comment: Secondly: you have given us the independent message of the error - but what would be more useful s the full stacktrace. Can you go check your logfiles (should be somehing like /logs/development.log) and find the error - then copy/paste the full stacktrace here? (should be about 20-30 lines of filenames with the error-message as just the first line)

Comment: that require/permit... what is the name of the method that it's in? (in fact, please just edit your question and add the code there)

Comment: getting the fulltrace now...the method is called  def participant_params

Comment: ok, then permitting/requiring is unlikely to be the problem as you aren't using that method from your invite action.

Comment: Are you running this in a server with the scrolling data? If so, can you please add something to your participant_invite method (the very first line) add: `puts params.inspect` then, run the action again and copy/paste what you get in the server window into your question? (not in the comments here - edit your question to add it) thanks.

Comment: ok, see this line: `app/controllers/participants_controller.rb:89` that says the error is occurring on line 89 -> what line is line 89?

Comment: that is     @participant = params[:participant_invite][:email].split(/,\s*/)
 on "try 2"

Comment: Unrelated note: you do not need to put an `@` in front of every variable name. You only need `@` if the variable is going to stick around and be displayed in the view... Likewise - it's good practice to use a plural variable name for something that represents a set of things... so for example, instead of `@participant` I'd use `participants`

Comment: cool - soit's obvious that the params you are getting are not what you are expecting to get. so please try the `puts`  thing so you know what params you are actually getting back

Comment: I tried that...but it doesn't look much different than the other trace (to my n00b eyes).  I put "puts params.inspect" directly after "def participant_invite"

Comment: Yes, but it's not the trace we want, but the set of params...

Comment: Because right now, it looks like all you're getting is this: `Parameters: {"e"=>"276"}`

Comment: my next big question is: If you're doing `form_for` - why are you passing in a different url?  because I think the url you are using is only taking in what you are passing into itself and ignoring the rest of the file... can you check the routes for this url? is it POST or GET?

Comment: This is how form_for should be used: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for

If you want to do a url that is not a standard RESTful route (like you are), then use form-tag: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/form_tag

(you will also have to convert the `f.email_field` to `email_field_tag` or similar to match see: http://apidock.com/rails/v4.1.8/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/email_field_tag)

Comment: ah.  I've never used a form for this purpose before, so I went with what I knew.  I've just moved the create! logic to a Post method (which I should have known better to do).  Your extra tips have been so helpful.

Comment: Do you have a working solution? If so - feel free to add it as an "answer" - it may ell help others who have a similar problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I figured it out and here's my solution

Controller

```
def participant_invite
 @event = Event.find(params[:e])
end  

def add_participants
  @event = Event.find(params[:e]) 
  @participant = params[:participant_invite][:email].split(/,\s*/)
  @participant.each do |t|
  newpart = Participant.new(:event_id => @event.id, :status => 'unseen')
  newpart.save
    EventMailer.notify_participant_new(newpart, @event,  @participant_invite ).deliver
  end
  redirect_to invited_participants_path(:e => @event.id )
end
```

view

```
 <%= form_for :participant_invite, url: add_participants_path(:e => @event.id) } do |f| %> 

 <%=    f.text_field :email, :placeholder => 'Email(s)'  %>

 <%= f.submit %>
```